# when is the filter(Viewer,TreePath,Object[]) method called?

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp, treeviewer, treepath

I have created and added a new filter to my `TreeViewer` object. It works fine but I cannot seem to understand when is the `filter(Viewer,TreePath,Object[])` called.

So the filter is actually an instance of a class which extends `ViewerFilter` and needs to implement the abstract method select. In my case, select always returns true and I filter the elements by overriding the `public Object[] filter(Viewer viewer, Object parent, Object[] elements)`.

However, when I try to override the `public Object[] filter(Viewer viewer, TreePath parentPath, Object[] elements)`, this function doesn't get called at all.

Here's how it looks:

```
    myTreeViewer.addFilter(new ViewerFilter()
    {
        @Override
        public Object[] filter(Viewer viewer, TreePath parentPath, Object[] elements)
        {
            /* doesn't get called */
            return elements;
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] filter(Viewer viewer, Object parent, Object[] elements)
        {
            /* gets called normally */
            return elements;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean select(Viewer arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I need to override the filter method with the `TreePath` argument in order to be afle to filter elements based on a specified level.

In the documentation I could only find the following explanation:

> Filters the given elements for the given viewer. The input array is not modified.
>   The default implementation of this method calls filter(Viewer, Object, Object[]) with the parent from the path. Subclasses may override

**Later edit**

In the end I could not find any way of having this function called so I implemented a workaround: I created a wrapper over my model instances that also has a "parent" field. Whenever I insert my instances into the tree (in my `getChildren` and `getElements` methods), I actually create instances of my wrapper and set the parents accordingly.

This way, whenever the `hasChildren` gets called, I can navigate from the current node to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code the Eclipse 'search references' says that nothing calls the `TreePath` version of `filter`.

Your `ITreeContentProvider` has a `getParent(object)` method which you can use to traverse the tree.

Comment: In my case it's more complicated because on different levels of the tree I can have the same instances of the model. That is, I can have a top level node which can also appear as a leaf (same model instance, that is, returned by my content provider). As a result, even if I'm on a leaf, the getParent() will return null if the same instance is also a top level node.